# Keeping track of changes in Dev Branch

Tags: version-control, tfs, branching-and-merging

I recently started taking an interest in using a branching model similar to Vincent Driessens [Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). We have multiple developers working on the same project so using different branches for different features is a big plus for us. The model states that after a feature is developed, it is merged back into the Development branch, and on a certain time a release branch will be created from it.

Now my problem is that I don't know who added what to the dev branch since the last release, but I do want to present a list of changes that will be implemented for the next one. So the question is, how do I know what features have been added to the dev branch?

We're using TFS for version control. As far as I know I have the following options:

- Better labeling and commenting of versions (currently there is no labeling and little commenting)
- Linking TFS tasks to versions (not sure how to create a nice list of that yet though)

Maybe I should just follow my own options above but I was curious about how you guys deal with this.

Comment: Not sure this should be tagged "git" since the question is really about how to make this work in TFS.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I've had the word Git too much in my head lately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest you take a look at the [TFS Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) as it will likely answer most of your questions.

> how do I know what features have been added to the dev branch?

I think the "develop" branch in Driessen's model is most closely equated to the "main" branch in the TFS guidance. I would suggest that you shouldn't merge changes into main unless they are already planned to go into the next release. Then when you are ready to release you simply branch from the latest version of main.

Keeping track of what features are intended for the next release is something that would be handled by the work item tracking system.

Separately, you may find the [Track Work Item](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2012/07/11/vs-tfs-2012-tidbits-merging-changes-by-work-item.aspx) feature of Team Explorer to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I haven't found the time to look into this yet but I'll be looking through the links in a few days.